# ¿Cómo sumar registros que contengan valores duplicados?

Tags: sql-server, datatables, tablas

Tengo una tabla donde tengo ajustes de movimientos de inventario, pero me salen muchos registros repetidos (porque se recibe parcialmente).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quisiera es que los datos que estén duplicados como ejemplo 1955 y que tenga el mismo código de OrdenDeCompra se sume la CantidadAjustada y se genere un solo renglón, junto que tome la fecha mas actual....

Comment: Quieres generar una consulta o quieres que los datos de la tabla se "arreglen" y modificarlos con los datos que estan en el momento en la tabla o crear un trigger o un SP para cuando ingresen datos a la tabla?

Comment: Seria bueno que se actualizaran (se borraran los datos y se generara una sola fila) pero con la pura consulta me bastaria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque la respuesta la dió el compañero @Harwin Edil Perez Salinas la explicaré mejor.

Para el caso de la consulta puedes usar las funciones de [SUM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) y [MAX](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) de SQL Server junto con la sentencia [GROUP BY](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) para que, como su nombre lo dice, agrupes los resultados de tu consulta.

Para tu caso entonces sería así

```sql
SELECT CodigoArticulo, TipoMovimiento, Comentario, MAX(FechaMovimiento) as FechaMovimiento, CantidadAnterior, Ajuste, SUM(cantidadAjustada) as CantidadAjustada, Usuario, OrdenDeCompra, CantidadOrdenDeCompra, Costo
FROM TablaMovimientos
GROUP BY CodigoArticulo, TipoMovimiento, Comentario, CantidadAnterior, Ajuste, Usuario, OrdenDeCompra, CantidadOrdenDeCompra, Costo
```

En el general, el problema de esta consulta seria que si dos usuarios diferentes hicieron movimientos al mismo articulo, te generará dos filas, por el agrupamiento del campo Usuario, para esto puedes resolverlo quitando el usuario o los campos que no sean relevantes o te están duplicando las filas (Debes quitarlos tanto del `SELECT` como del `GROUP BY`) algo tal que así:

```sql
SELECT CodigoArticulo, TipoMovimiento, MAX(FechaMovimiento) as FechaMovimiento, SUM(cantidadAjustada) as CantidadAjustada,
FROM TablaMovimientos
GROUP BY CodigoArticulo, TipoMovimiento
```

Adicional puedes agregar la sentencia `WHERE` para hacer mas rapida tu consulta, dado el caso:

```sql
SELECT CodigoArticulo, TipoMovimiento, MAX(FechaMovimiento) as FechaMovimiento, SUM(cantidadAjustada) as CantidadAjustada,
FROM TablaMovimientos
GROUP BY CodigoArticulo, TipoMovimiento
WHERE CodigoArticulo = 1955
```

Ya si quisieras hacer un proceso automático, tendrías que crear un [Store Procedure](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15) para llamar en tu aplicación o un [Trigger](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/sql-server-create-trigger/) para que se ejecute cuando inserten un registro en la tabla.

Pero esto es mas complejo dado que tendrías que hacer el select pero actualizar el registro, hacer recorridos y demás, y perderias los otros datos de los registros anteriores como el usuario que hace el movimiento, los comentarios y demás y solo tendrías al final un único registro y no todo su historial de pagos. Por lo que recomiendo hacer la solución a nivel de tu aplicación para mostrar el total y más bien crear la opción que traiga el historial de pagos que sería mostrar la info histórica (lo que tienes en tu tabla) para ese producto.

Comment: El código de articulo si lo agregare en el reporte, ya que lo estoy pasando a crystal reports pero es en Visual Basic 6 (si de antaño), pero me quedo mucho msa claro con tu explicacion, de hecho hice un Stored Procedure para crear la tabla que tengo, de otras tablas...

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido, te agradeceria si calificas que respuesta es la que responde tu pregunta, un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Podrías utilizar las funciones de sumarización:

```
select CodigoArticulo,TipoMovimiento,Comentario,max(FechaMovimiento) as FechaMovimiento,CantidadAnterior,Ajuste,sum(cantidadAjustada) as CantidadAjustada,Usuario,OrdenDeCompra,CantidadOrdenDeCompra,Costo
from TUTABLA
group by CodigoArticulo,TipoMovimiento,Comentario,CantidadAnterior,Ajuste,Usuario,OrdenDeCompra,CantidadOrdenDeCompra,Costo
```

Obtendrás una tupla con la fecha máxima y la suma de cantidadAjustada.
Ojala de ayude.

Comment: Editar y agregar una explicación ayudaría a hacer más entendible lo que propones en tu aporte